# File splitting alternatives to edit SQL flat file headers

Tags: sql-server

I have a 50gb text file (comma delimited) that has duplicate header names.

I'd like to import this file into a new table, but the SQL Server Import Wizard is complaining about the duplicate header names.

It took 2.5 hours to create the file via a very simple table join + export. Adding other SQL instructions to the query does not seem to be an option, because based on my test runs, adding additional instructions to the query makes it take way too long.

Is it possible to open just the first part of the file to edit the headers manually? This seems like a better option than splitting the file.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone has this issue, open the file using a Hex Editor (HxD).

This will open the hard drive map of the file, and it streams the information rather than loading the entire file.

Then I changed the first character of the common headers to a number, so instead of Account and Account, I have Account and 8ccount. Doesn't allow you to insert characters by default, at least. It overwrites the data.

When you save, it first creates a backup, so that does take a while if it's a very big file (plus you'll need the space). Perhaps you can turn off this setting and brave it without a backup.